# How can I add to the terminal's scrollback using ncurses?

Tags: ncurses

I'm writing an app using ncurses which displays the status of tests running on multiple machines.  It displays several progress bars at the bottom of the screen, and a failure log above them.  However, the log may easily be longer than the rest of the terminal.

I'd like to have excess log roll off the top in such a way that if the user scrolls their terminal up they'll see the rest of the log.  This is what happens when you scroll through a file using `less`; it replaces the current view with the next page, but the text you've passed ends up in the terminal's scrollback.

How can I get ncurses to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out this is easy.  I just put a window at the top of the screen, made it scrollable (`scrollok`), and `addstr`'d text to it until it scrolled.  The text scrolled right off into the scrollback without trouble.

Comment: Doesn't seem to work, at least with ncurses 5.7 and Mac OS X 10.6's Terminal.app or xterm. :(

Comment: You can take a look at my code here: https://github.com/Peeja/multi_progress_bar.  With apologies for long URLs, the relevant lines are https://github.com/Peeja/multi_progress_bar/blob/master/lib/multi_progress_bar.rb#L21 and https://github.com/Peeja/multi_progress_bar/blob/master/lib/multi_progress_bar.rb#L50

Comment: Thanks for posting, but that gives me the same behavior (the ncurses interface immediately takes over the entire visible area of the terminal and when the program exits the original contents are restored).  Worth noting that `less` behaves the same way on my computer...

Comment: Huh.  Are you using Terminal.app, or iTerm, or something else?  It might be emulator dependent.

Comment: I assume that Peeja is interested in having a large scrollback while the application is running, whereas Miles wants the scrollback to persist after the application is running.

Comment: I'm also curious, here. This is relevant to my work (although I'm not using NCurses.)

Comment: What most terminal emulators seem to do is to redraw/restore the screen part, while leaving the scrollback alone. You have two options here: one is to disable the alternate screen feature a la http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8496602/vim-restore-shell-on-exit (which will keep the content on the screen; not sure how to in ncurses, but I'm sure there's an option), and the other is to forcibly scroll content off the top of the top window just before exit (which will leave the content just off the top of the screen).