# vim restore shell on exit

Tags: vim

I just installed Arch on my new computer and I can not figure out what command I need to add to .vimrc in order for it to restore shell contents (before vim was called) on exit.

That is, I want my shell to look like this:

```
# whoami
root
# who
root tty1 2011-12-11 16:42
# vim somefile.txt
#
```

But instead it looks something like this:

```
1 hello
2 how is it going?
~
~
~
~
~
~
~
~
#
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually, it can not do that, unless your terminal supports alternate screen. And for those that do (xterm, gnome-terminal), I believe, `vim` does it automatically (relevant option is `restorescreen`).

Answer (score 1):

http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-general-1/disable-the-clear-after-you-close-vi-657233/#post3221832

Or to summarize

```
set t_ti= t_te=
```